# rsv validation by Benjamin Keen own function doesn't work properly?

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying benjamin's keens [RSV validation](http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/rsv/) script (jquery version), but with an own function it doesn't work. my custom function returns false but the oncompletehandler is still called??

```
$("#testForm").RSV({
    onCompleteHandler: myOnComplete,
    displayType: "alert-one",
    rules: [
      "required,first_name,Please enter your first name.",
    "required,last_name,Please enter your last name.",
    "required,email,Please enter your email address.",
    "valid_email,email,Please enter a valid email address.",
      "function,testfunct",

    ]
  });




function testFunc() {
        tmpName = $('#tmpName').val();
        if (tmpName != '') {
            //alert ("name has been set");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert ("Credit card empt");
            $('#tmpName').focus();
            return false;
            }
     }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your customized function is not correct. It is expected to return:

- true  when validation passed.
- an array (but not "false") when validation failed.

more details please refer to its [official document](http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/rsv/jquery/) , then click the item: "Custom validation rules"

> In order for your function to interact properly with the RSV script, your function must have a well-defined return value. Namely:
>
> If the field passes whatever test or tests you administer, it must explicitly return true.
>      If it fails the test(s), it has to return an array of arrays, like so:
>
> ```
>  return [[node1, "error message1"], [node2, "error message2"], [node3, "error message3"]];
> ```
>
> Or if your function is just throwing a single error:
>
> ```
>  return [[node, "error message"]];
> ```
>
> Note the double [[ and ]]. That's a not a typo!